# Is it correct to say that if $E(|X|^k)$ is not finite then kth moment is either undefined or diverges to $\pm\infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I've been reading some discussions regarding the difference between undefined and infinite moments like [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117200/infinite-moments-or-moments-dont-exist).

My book states that the kth moment only exists when  $E(|X|^k)$ is finite. If $E(|X|^k)\to\infty$, does this mean that, for $k$ even, then the kth moment diverges to $\infty$, and for $k$ odd,  kth moment is either an indeterminant form like $\infty-\infty$ or diverges to $\pm\infty$?

Comment: Since you have absolute values under $E$ it can not possibly be $-\infty$ or $\infty-\infty$. It is either zero, or positive finite, or positive infinite. You are probably confusing moments with absolute moments.

Comment: @Conifold Sorry that was a typo, the last expectation should be the kth moment $E(X^k)$, not the absolute moment

Comment: *All* of them should be that for the post to make sense, including the one in the title.

Comment: @Conifold My question actually relates to the distinction between the moment and absolute moment when the latter $\to\infty$. My book states that $\mu_k = E(X^k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^kf_X(x)dx$ only exists when $E(|X|^k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|^kf_X(x)dx$ is finite. I am curious on the possible values for $\mu_k=E(X^k)$ if $E(|X|^k)\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E|Y| <\infty$ iff $EY^{+} <\infty$ and $EY^{-} <\infty$. If both the conditions fail then $EY$ is not defined and $E|Y|=\infty$. If one of them is finite and the other one is $\infty$ then $EY=\infty$ or $EY=-\infty$. Apply this to $Y=X^{k}$. Note that for $k$ even there is no chance of $EX^{k}$ being $-\infty$.