# Expected Value formula

Tags: probability

[image]

This is a continuous probability exercise which is pretty simple but when I got to part C I was doing the normal integration and I got it wrong because I used X to find the expected value of X instead of absolute (X) . Now I'v been taking this course for 3 months and this is the first time I see absolute (X) , why did they use it ?

Comment: The expectation exists when the integral is absolutely convergent, hence the absolute value. However, to get the value of the expectation, remove the absolute value.

Comment: Random variable with Cauchy distribution doesn't have moments. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution

Comment: Does absolutely convergent has to do with the need to check that we aren't find the mean of an infinite left part with an infinite right part (by right and left I mean the positive axis and the negative axis) , as if we are finding the difference of two infinities , right ? But it turned out that even thought each part is infinitely far , the mean is 0 , how come , and can you give an example ?

Comment: "the mean is 0" The mean of what? Please be specific (if you try to be, you should see the problem right away).

Comment: The mean of the random variable X

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60766/what-is-the-result-of-infinity-minus-infinity

Comment: "The mean of the random variable X" No.