# Graphically, the limit is 0, but algebraically, why isn't it 1?

Tags: limits, exponential-function, infinity

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x-x^2} = 0$$

I'm a bit lost on this one. Graphically, it tends to 0, hence the limit is 0. But, how could I prove it algebraically?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^x-x^2=\infty$

Comment: Make sure that you have the correct function.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I corrected the equation.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani Thank you for pointing that out. I missed a couple of curly braces around the exponent.

Comment: Why would it be $1$ in the first place, exactly? Because substitution (naively!) gives "$\infty - \infty$" in the exponent?

Comment: $x-x^2\to -\infty$ thus $e^{x-x^2}\to 0$

Comment: Are you familiar with L'hopital's rule?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer This is why I am asking here. I thought $$\infty-\infty$$ = 0

Comment: $\infty-\infty$ is indeterminate; cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60766/what-is-the-result-of-infty-infty)

Comment: Well, intuitively, the reason why is because $x^2$ "grows faster" than $x$. So $x-x^2$ goes towards $-\infty$ instead, since $x^2$ dominates the value of the function.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I am very familiar with the L'hopital's rule. However, I am doing a review on this textbook and L'hopital's rule isn't mentioned yet.

Comment: @binibiningtinamoran [$\infty - \infty$ _does not_ equal $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60766/what-is-the-result-of-infty-infty/60783#60783). It is an indeterminate form, just like $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: $x-x^2$ isn't less than $0$ for all $x$, just for $x$ such that $x<0,x>1$, one or the other. (Of course, if $x\to\infty$, that condition is met.) Also, it's not $e$ raised to the power of *anything* negative, but rather $e$ to an exponent such that said exponent goes to $-\infty$ in the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, $e^{-x^2}$ goes to zero very fast.  If you know $\lim_{x \to \infty}e^{-x}=0$ you can just say that $x-x^2 \lt -x$ for $x \gt 2$, so $e^{x-x^2} \lt e^{-x} \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{x-x^2}=e^{x(1-x)}$. This means that when $x$ goes to $\infty$, the exponent goes to $\infty\cdot(-\infty)=-\infty$, and $e^{-\infty}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x-x^2} = \lim_ {x\to\infty} \frac {e^x}{e^{x^2}} = \lim_ {x\to\infty} \frac {1}{e^{x^2-x}} = 1/{\infty} = 0 $$