# Notation: $\log(\infty)$

Tags: notation, logarithms

In the context of infinite series and indefinite integrals involving $\log(x)$, it's possible to have to substitute $\infty$ into $\log(x)$.

I've seen a paper, where this was marked:
$$\log(x)\space |_{1}^{\infty} = \lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\log(a)-\log(1)$$

The reason for using limits is claimed to be that $\infty$ is not a number.
But why is the limit conception more useful?

Comment: No,the times you put $\infty$ as a upper/lower limit (integration, sums, etc) you mean that precise limit at the other side of your equality.

Comment: Where have you ever seen $\log(\infty)$ in a paper?

Comment: @CameronBuie I'm asking for the reason for using the limit notation instead of $\log(\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We expect that a number has some properties that $\infty$ has not, e.g. the fact that for $a,b>0 \rightarrow a+b>a$, but this simple properties is not valid if $a=\infty$. So $\infty$ is not a number (but for a better discussion of this topic you can see: [Is infinity a number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36289/is-infinity-a-number)).

So $\log (\infty)$ has not a meaning as a number, but it can be used as a shortcut for the notation $ \log (\infty)=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \log x$, and this has a precise mathematical meaning thanks to the definition of [limit at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_at_infinity).