# Is $1/\infty=0{}$?

Tags: infinity

If $1\div0=\infty$, then $1\div(1\div0)=0$.
Does this mean $1\div\infty=0$?
Or is it always close to zero?

Please let me know what is correct: either it's zero or always close to zero.

Comment: You can relatively consistently assume that $1/\infty=0$. BUT, you should never assume that the usual rules of arithmetic are valid, when the calculations involve $\infty$ or division by zero. You need to be very careful what you mean. For example, there is no way to define $0/0, \infty/\infty$ or $\infty-\infty$ without breaking something. Basically: $\infty$ is not a number, so you should not assume it follows the same rules that numbers obey.

Comment: Tnx sir i am clear now

Comment: To talk about closeness you should talk first about limits.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen well, [$\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2387331/169535) [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2387292/169535) [actually](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2387295/169535) [a number](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2387290/169535) ;) (or at least if you agree with the answers)

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician, the page you linked was closed a year ago as being unclear. It seems unusual to close this question because it is allegedly a duplicate of an unclear closed question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer depends on how you interpret the expression $\frac{1}{\infty}$.

(1) If you interpret it as the limit of $\frac{1}{n}$ as $n$ tends to infinity then the answer is $0$: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$.

(2) On the other hand, if you interpret $\infty$ as a specific infinite number $H$ in a modern theory of infinitesimals such as [Robinson's framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis) then the answer is that the ratio $\frac{1}{H}$ is "close to zero", namely an [infinitesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal).

In fact answers (1) and (2) are really the same answer because one can view the limit of a function $f(n)$ as the [standard part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_part_function) of $\frac{1}{H}$: $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=\text{st}(f(H))$, and the standard part of an infinitesimal is zero.

Answer (score 13):

This will depend on what mathematical model you use to model $\infty$. Different models may give different answers depending on what, precisely, "$\infty$" means.

The model you are probably *thinking* of, however, is most likely one of the following two, which are very similar:

1. the *extended real number line*, $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$
2. the *projective real number line* $\hat{\mathbb{R}}$

Both are based on taking the usual real number line and adjoining either two or one, respectively, additional objects, which you could call as numbers, but perhaps better as *ideal points*: in the first case, $\infty$ (or $+\infty$) and $-\infty$, in the second, only $\infty$. These are explicit objects just like the numbers that we are inserting into the set, by the way, not just abuse of the symbol off of a limit. Then it is made as a *definition* that $\frac{1}{\infty} = 0$ in both systems (same for $-\infty$). For the first system, the following are defined:

$$a \infty = \infty, a \ne 0$$
$$\frac{a}{\pm \infty} = 0, a \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$a \pm \infty = \pm \infty, a \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$\infty + \infty = \infty$$
$$(-\infty) + (-\infty) = -\infty$$

But *no other operations involving $\infty$ are defined*, such as $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ (note the "$a \in \mathbb{R}$" restriction), $\frac{\infty}{0}$, etc. nor is $\frac{a}{0}$. In the second system (projective, where $\infty = -\infty$) $\frac{a}{0} = \infty$ as well (for $a \in \mathbb{R}$) except when $a = 0$, where it is undefined. But also there, $\infty + \infty$ is undefined as well, in particular, the last two rules above do not hold.

Why are these definitions used? The intuition they attempt to capture is that "plugging $\pm \infty$ should give you the limit at infinity" of the operation - that is, in this system we inject a real point "at infinity" into the number system and then ask to "extend by continuity" there as though we were "filling in a removable singularity". Where this fails to happen, the operation involving infinite points is undefined. If $a$ is a fixed real number, then $f(x) = a + x$ approaches $\infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, so we define $a + \infty = \infty$ in the extended real number line. But $\infty - \infty$ is *not* defined, since the limit $\lim_{(a, b) \rightarrow (\infty, \infty)} a - b$ *does not exist*: it depends on the precise path by which $a$ and $b$ go toward $\infty$. This is also why "$\infty - \infty$" when not considered as extended real numbers but rather as standing for a form of a limit (so "$\infty$" *is* now just "a symbol off a limit"), is called as indeterminate form.