# Why is the bounded functions not a sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I know that the presheaf of bounded functions is not a sheaf but I don't see why. I checked in wikipedia they say that this presheaf does not verify **the axiom of "Glue"**. For me it verifies this axiom. Indeed, if U and V are open sets, and f and g are bounded functions on U and V respectively, and they agree on the intersection, then combining them in the obvious way - let h(x) = f(x) if x is in U, g(x) if x is in V, is a bounded function with the bound being max(|f|, |g|). Do you think I don't understand well what gluing means?

Thanks.

Comment: The functions may glue together to form an unbounded function.

Comment: The covering needs not be finite, so your $\max(\lvert f\rvert,\lvert g\rvert)$ is not really a bound.

Comment: I don't see why? If you define $h$ (by gluing) as I did I don't see why it's unbounded? @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Maybe you're right, but I still don't understand we could take $max(f_{i})$ @SaucyO'Path

Comment: Because $\max\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\cdots\}=\boxed{??}$.

Comment: I still don't agree, if we take for example $max{\frac{1}{2^{î}}}$ it's bounded. I see your point, but if we have everything is bounded I think we can define $max$ @SaucyO'Path

Comment: Ok, feel free to ignore the point.

Comment: I am not ignoring anything I would like just to understand @SaucyO'Path

Comment: You may not be glueing two functions, you may be glueing infinitely many functions.

Comment: I see your point. But in the definition there is no restriction about the number of function. I agree with you but if you give me a mathematical proof of this I would be happy and it would be very useful @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Maybe your confusion also arose from the fact that the values of an infinite amount of bounded functions can tend to infinity even though none of the values of the functions on the subsets of the cover is infinite anywhere. This amounts to the question why infinity is not included in the natural numbers even though the number of natural numbers is infinite. For more information on that see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36289/is-infinity-a-number

Answer (score 4):

Let us take the $\mathcal{F}$ presheaf of bounded real functions on the real line $\mathbb{R}$. Then for each $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ open we have 
$$
U \mapsto \mathcal{F}(U) = \{ f\colon U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \mid \sup_U |f| < \infty \}
$$
It is clearly a presheaf. Now let's see the sheaf requirements.

Fix $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ and an open covering $U=\cup_i U_i$.

1. For $s,t \in \mathcal{F}(U)$, we need that
   $$
   s|_{U_i} = t|_{U_i}, \forall i \Rightarrow s=t
   $$
2. For a family $\{s_i \in \mathcal{F}(U_i)\}$ we need that
   $$
   s_i|_{U_i\cap U_j} = s_j|_{U_i\cap U_j}, \forall i,j \Rightarrow \exists s \in \mathcal{F}(U) \mid s|_{U_i}= s_i
   $$

It is not hard to see that 1. holds. Now for 2. take $U_i = (i-2,i+2)$ an open interval for each $i\in \mathbb{Z}$. We have $\mathbb{R} = \cup U_i$. Define
$$
s_i\colon U_i \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, \, s_i(t) = t
$$
Then $\sup_{U_i} |s_i| = \max\{|i-2|,|i+2|\}$ and $s_i \in \mathcal{F}(U_i)$. Suppose that there exists $s\in\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $s|_{U_i}= s_i$. Let $N \in \mathbb{Z}$ be such that $N> \sup_{\mathbb{R}} |s|$. Then we have an absurd since 
$$
s(N) = s_N(N) = N > \sup_{\mathbb{R}} |s|.
$$